# Persist Class as key value pair SQL Table

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jackson, hashmap, gson

I have a class with multiple value types.

I want to save it as key-value pair.

Let's say we have a class

```
class MyClass{
String p1;
Double p2;
}
```

I want it in DB as

```
id | a | b  | c
1  | - | -  | -


id |fkId  | propetyName | propertyValue
1  |1     | p1           | hello
2  |1     | p2           | 10
```

Comment: You are talking about an EAV Model (Entity Attribute Value). But why does your class have a name? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model#:~:text=Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value%20model%20(,given%20entity%20is%20relatively%20modest.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli here I am trying to intercept different classes and save them in DB. Just creating something like middleware.

Comment: Wy don't you use JSON to store the data? Like this https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-schema-less-eav-entity-attribute-value-data-using-json-and-hibernate/